# Angular 2 animations/transitions only working on chrome?

Tags: firefox, animation, angular, cross-browser, transition

As the title says, I've been building a web app using Angular2 and decided to test cross-browser, only to find the nifty animations working only in Chrome. Here is what one of my components looks like if that might make any difference:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'contact',
  templateUrl: 'app/about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/about.component.css'],
  
  host: {
     '[@routeAnimation]': 'true',
     '[style.position]': "'absolute'",
     '[style.margin]':"'auto'",
     '[style.text-align]':"'center'",
     '[style.width]':"'100%'",
     '[style.display]':"'block'"

     
    
   },
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [
      state('*', style({transform:            'translateX(0)', opacity: 1})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(100%)',   opacity: 0}),
        animate(500)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', animate(500, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0})))
    ])
  ],
   
})
```

What might I be missing/What could I try to implement in order to have cross-browser functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From 'https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html':

> Angular animations are built on top of the standard Web Animations API
>   and they run natively on browsers that support it.

The Web Animation API is not well supported right now. Please check: http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation

You need to use a polyfill to get the animations working. This one https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js can be used.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import polyfills to support Web Animations for these brwosers.

Add these lines in your **src/polyfills.ts**:

```
/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. 
   http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
**/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

However, web animations are supposed to work with Chrome, Firefox and Opera without importing this polyfill.